# Azure App Service authorization/easy auth is conflicting ASP.NET Forms auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, forms-authentication

I want to enable App Service Authentication to protect development environment from public access.
The App Service authentication itself is working fine, only people from our company Azure AD are allowed, all good.

But it is conflicting with the authentication of the website itself, after authenticating through Azure AD the website sees you as you are already logged in. 
And I don't understand how exactly it ends up conflicting, we are using Forms authentication, I've tried explicitly naming the cookie that forms auth should look for, and setting it to always use cookies for authentication, yet it's still conflicting.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/sign-in" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />
 </authentication>
```

After logging in through microsoft, I see there's no .ASPXAUTH cookie, only AppServiceAuthSession, yet Forms auth sees me as logged in.

Comment: Are your users on a specific network? You could avoid the problem by protecting your app using network rules in the App Service instead of adding Azure AD on top. (See Azure Portal -> AppService -> Networking -> Access Restrictions). Getting two level authentication with AD and Form authentication to work seems difficult. See https://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/ (you would need to switch the order - the AD page first, then the Form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this by removing the auth setting in web.config and use OWIN to inject a middleware (CustomMiddleware) before Authentication of the website itself. If user is authenticated by your CustomMiddleware, you carry on with your regular flow otherwise short circuit the request flow. In CustomMiddleware you can inspect the request headers, body etc to have authenticated cookie etc. I guess you have MVC style pipeline in your application. There are number of resources on internet which you can explore. One example is below.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/how-to-add-custom-middleware-aspnet-core

Comment: I was hoping it would work without changing authorization mechanism on the server. E.g. we have a php dashboard protected by easy auth that works as intended - login with microsoft to access the website itself, then login to the php dashboard through it's own mechanisms. Unfortunately with ASP.NET it seems to be getting in each other's way.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it conflicts in the first place? From my understanding, the Forms authentication is supposed to authenticate me based on .ASPXAUTH cookie, that's what it's configured to do. Yet after authenticating through easy auth, there's no cookie and the website still sees me as authenticated. For example in that php website, I can clearly see a cookie responsible for being logged in, if I delete it, it logs me out from the dashboard, but I'm still on the site because I'm still logged in through easy auth.

Comment: From experience, such conflicts arise due to the precedence set by the ASP .Net framework and absence of logic around multiple auth setup. In your case, the AD Auth is setup in Startup file and Forms auth is declared in Web.config. So, how does the ASP .net runtime know if these are in series or one takes precedence over other? I am not sure if we can do that by your way. Hence, the OWIN middleware style has become popular which gives you fine grained control over the request pipeline and easy to debug multi auth setup in your case. Hope that makes sense.